Prove L is not Büchi-recognisable
I have a question which I would like to check if my proof is valid for:
Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet consisting of at least two different symbols, and let L be the following
$\omega$-language:
$\{\omega|\omega = u^{\omega}, u \in \Sigma^{*}\}$
Prove that L is not Büchi-recognisable.
If our alphabet is $\{0,1,2\}$, so we can have $u=012$, so $012012\dots \in L$, we can also have a word $v=01$, again $0101\dots \in L$, for both $u$ and $v$ each reach an accepting state, and as there are a finite number of them there will be some words that "land" on same acceptance state. So we can create a $\omega$ word $vu^{\omega}$ that will go will be accepted by the BA, however this word is not in $L$ as the start is never repeated.

The hypothesis is that the alphabet has at least two different symbols, so you cannot assume it contains at least three. Also you should differentiate the letter $w$ (double-u) and $\omega$ (omega), because as is, $\omega=u^{\omega}$ makes little sense.

We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See here and here. Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.

This is a site where people can collaborate to build an archive of knowledge, in the form of high-quality questions and answers that will hopefully be useful to others in the future.

Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/170377/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4999108/14578.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.
